# How define a function key in keychord/key-seq?

Tags: key-chord-mode

I have the following configuration for keychord:

```
(key-chord-define evil-normal-state-map "fk" 'evil-window-up)`
```

With the timing option, I'm still able to do some operations with the original `f` function, like find character `k` with <kbd>f</kbd>, after waiting 0.4 seconds. If I do <kbd>fk</kbd> inside 0.4 seconds, then he will go the adjacent window up.

Now I want to bind the keysequence <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>f9</kbd> to do something.

When I configure this:

```
(key-chord-define evil-normal-state-map "f<f9>" 'evil-window-up)`
```

Then I get an error: `(error: "Key-chord key must have two elements")`.

Another suggestion, to let keychord accept these keys?

Comment: What kind of first argument does `key-chord-define` expect? How does it parse the string? E.g., how does it know you don't want a sequence of 4 keys, `f`, `<`, `f`, `9`, and `>`? Perhaps you need to use `kbd` somewhere? What does `C-h f `key-chord-define` tell you?

Comment: `C-h f key-chord-define` gives me the following: http://pastebin.com/LFQUdbVh so I propably need to find out what the ASCII code is for function F9 key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`key-chord`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el) does not support binding Function keys as a part of key chords.

Below is the information regarding that from the "Limitations" section in that package's documentation header.

```
;; Emacs will not call input-method-function for keys that have non numeric
;; codes or whos code is outside the range 32..126. Thus you cannot define
;; key chords involving function keys, control keys, or even your non-english
;; letters (on national keyboards) that otherwise are well positioned for
;; chording on your keyboard.
;; (I think chording left and right arrow keys would be useful, but cannot do.
;; I consider this a bug in Emacs. Input methods could happily return 
;; unmodified *any* key they don't know about.)
```

Comment: Well, that's bad to read it. I validated your answer, because it was an answer on my question, even it didn't solved up my case.  Thanks for your reply.