# How map a prefix key, but keep the other keys untouched?

Tags: key-bindings

How could I remap the keycombination `f` and `<F9>`, without affecting the other Evil operations?

For example, I have the following

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "f <f9>") 'foobar)
```

So I press <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd>, then `foobar` will be called.

However, now I'm facing another problem. The <kbd>f</kbd>-key is not functioning anymore for other Evil operations. It works only for <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>f9</kbd> and not for finding character `a` with <kbd>fa</kbd>.

I understand the logic here. I understand why this issue has risen. But I'm struggling with the question how I could invent some workaround for this, and use the keycombination <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>f9</kbd>.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This issue is not specific to Evil, consider changing the question to target Emacs generally.

Comment: You're better informed about Evil than me. I always thought the Evil prefixes were special ones. Appearently not, I changed the title and OP.

Comment: Too many unknown (unstated) moving parts? IIRC, you use key-chord, Evil, and who-knows-what else. And you don't really provide a recipe and clear description of your problem and what you want instead. Try starting from `emacs -Q` and narrowing down your problem to something concrete (show code) and reproducible. You will typically get *much* better help that way. Plus, you will likely learn more just by the exercise. **Just a suggestion.**

Comment: `f` is bound to a command in `evil-normal-map`, so you're going to have to replace or modify that command one way or another. Perhaps some around advice which tests the value of `char` (once it has been supplied), and performs your special behaviour when appropriate, and otherwise allows the default behaviour to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Vim and Emacs have different approaches to keymaps.  Keep in mind that the following sentences are merely observations I've made over time, I do neither know how they're actually implemented (yet), nor do I condemn either approach.  They do only serve to explain the expectations of the questioner and how these differ from reality.

In Vim you're allowed to bind nearly any key sequence to a sequence of commands, even if these involve switches between Vim modes or insertion of text.  In case a key sequence is used on its own *and* as prefix for other key sequences, Vim utilizes a timeout to decide whether to prefer the shorter key sequence.  This is done in a transparent manner, in fact quite a number of Vim users aren't aware of this feature unless they use it for the insert mode where delays are much more noticable (or customize the respective setting for it).

In Emacs there is a sharp distinction between standalone keys and prefixes.  A key can be only bound to either of those.  There do exist a number of workarounds for this, including using hackery with timers (see `key-chord.el`) and devising commands that can read in extra input on their own.  Evil makes use of the latter and on some occasions of the former as well (see its handling of the escape key).

The former approach with `key-chord.el` is reasonably popular, but [was tried by the author already](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17212/how-define-a-function-key-in-keychord-key-seq) and disregarded because `key-chord.el` simply doesn't support function keys.  Given its implementation and limitations, it's about time for someone else to step up and create a more powerful package... Maybe some other day, I've only toyed around with [rate-limiting keys](https://github.com/wasamasa/jammer) so far.

This leaves the other approach.  It's not ideal as it doesn't compose (all multiplexing must be defined manually and cannot be properly done by external packages at all), but good enough for customization:

```
(defun my-evil-find-char (arg char)
  (interactive (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg) (read-key)))
  (cond
   ((characterp char)
    (evil-find-char arg char))
   ((eq char 'f9)
    (foobar))
   (t
    (user-error "Unknown key combination"))))

(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "f") 'my-evil-find-char)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Are you sure that your customization works? When I do fa, he brings me right to the character a. When I do f f9, I got the message `Wrong type argument: stringp, f9. `

Comment: Works fine for me.  `eq` does compare objects by identity, so this kind of error shouldn't even happen as it just returns `t` or `nil`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, it turned out that the error was caused by the package `evil-snipe`. I really appreciate your help in this case. I validated your answer. I would like to learn from it. Could you tell me what the `prefix-numeric-value` and  `current-prefix-arg` means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)` equals `"p"` in `interactive`.  It interprets the prefix argument as if it were a number.  So, by default it's 1, with the universal argument it's 4 and with a numerical prefix argument it's whatever the number was that you've entered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I intend to learn a lot from Emacs/Elisp, in order to configure it myself and not asking such questions anymore on Emacs Stackexchange. Your help is really appreciated, thanks for that!